# How to sort one column and then another within it in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
state   num
-------------------------
ca      20
ny      30
ca      50
ca      10
ny      70
ny      90
```

What I want is to produce this:

```
state   num
-------------------------
ca      50
ca      20
ca      10
ny      90
ny      70
ny      30
```

Basically, I want the state column to be sorted, and then within each state, have the num sorted as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `select * from t order by state, num desc`?

Comment: Your results don't align with your sample data, is that just a typo?

Comment: @Stu oops，you're right. Updated the result table.

Answer (score 2):

specify both column you want to sort one separated by a comma :

```
select state, num from table_name order by 1, 2 desc
```

or

```
select state, num from table_name order by state, num desc
```

(seems like you wanted the first column sorted on `asc` way while the second one in `desc` way)

Comment: This is not correct, I need the num and the state to match. They should be part of the same row.

Comment: Sorting by position is something that many people dislike for reducing maintainability. (E.g. add a column to the select clause or remove it and you suddenly end up with your results in the wrong order.)

Comment: yes, that's why i've given both ways of ordering :) not all queries finish in some code you have to maintain. For a quick exec on a console, the first option is handy, even more when the select is using some complex expressions like truncate on dates etc :)

Comment: @sweetlemon you're remarks doesn't make any sense. are `state` and `num` two columns from different tables that you are joining ?

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM yourtablename ORDER BY state, num DESC

Comment: This is not correct, I need the num and the state to match. They should be part of the same row.

Comment: @sweetlemon: This doesn't seem to make sense. This query selects rows from the table (and in each row there is a num and a state) and the query orders the rows by state in ascenting order and within each state by num descendingly. Exactly as you described the problem and as your expected result suggests.